# HTML CSS onscreeen keyboad causes elements to overlap?

Tags: html, css

I am not a html or css developer but I need to create a one of html page. It looks fairly right only I want work a few things out.

My first issue is that I cant remove the light grey box around my embeded image, I'm of the understanding this is my padding but even with it set to 0px as well as the borer and margin set to 0px I have had no luck?

The second issue I have is that when used on a smartphone the logo, textboxes and button condense toward eachother and overlap... the cause of this is tyhe keyboad that pops up the solution iscompleatly unknowen to me.

the code is as follows:

```css
.ApplicationLogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  /* Half the width */
  margin-top: -60px;
  /* Half the height */
  content: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}

.LoginField {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 350px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-left: -175px;
  /* Half the width */
  margin-top: -300px;
  /* Half the height */
  border-radius: 25px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.UsernameTextbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 285px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -148px;
  /* Half the width */
  margin-top: -25px;
  /* Half the height */
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* Font Styling */
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #A9A9A9;
  /* Textbox Boarder Styling */
  border: 3px solid #A9A9A9;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.UsernameTextbox:hover {
  /* Font Styling */
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ff8000;
}

.UsernameTextbox:hover::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.PasswordTextbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 57%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 285px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -148px;
  /* Half the width */
  margin-top: -25px;
  /* Half the height */
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* Font Styling */
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #A9A9A9;
  /* Textbox Boarder Styling */
  border: 3px solid #A9A9A9;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.PasswordTextbox:hover::placeholder {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: transparent;
}

.PasswordTextbox:hover {
  /* Font Styling */
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ff8000;
}

.PasswordTextbox:hover::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.LoginButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 295px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -148px;
  /* Half the width */
  margin-top: -25px;
  /* Half the height */
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Font Styling */
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  /* Textbox Boarder Styling */
  border: 3px solid #A9A9A9;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.LoginButton:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.CopyrightFooter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 97%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -175px;
  /* Half the width */
  /* Font Styling */
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #A9A9A9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body id="BackgroundImage">
  <div class="LoginField"></div>
  <img class="ApplicationLogo" />
  <form method="POST" action="Confirm_Login">
    <div class="LogInControlls">
      <input class="UsernameTextbox" type="text" name="MYUSERNAME" placeholder="Username" required><br>
      <input class="PasswordTextbox" type="password" name="MYPASSWORD" placeholder="Password" required><br>
      <input class="LoginButton" type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="CopyrightFooter">van Tuyl Systems copyright &copy; 2021</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please do not post multiple problems in a single question. Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem.

Comment: The problem is that you used an `img` element without a `src` attribute - which makes the browser think this is a "broken image", and as such it gets displayed as an empty rectangle with a gray border. You still see what you expected to see, because you applied the actual image as a _background_ image for this element. Either use the data URI as the value of the src attribute - or use a different HTML element, if you want to keep using this as a background image.

Comment: CBore, okay i chucked it in a div element and indeed the grey outline disappeard thankyou so mucj=h for your explanation :)